# Python How can I set up global logger setting in multi python files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I just started Python and I am struggling to use Logger. I have two python files: app.py and liba.py. I want to setup logging at app.py and use it for liba.py (and another libraries). Do you have any good ideas or can you share any references?

file structure

```
entry.py
lib/liba.py
```

app.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from lib import liba

handler = logging.FileHandler('/tmp/app.log', 'a+')
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.warn('sample')

liba.out()
```

lib/liba.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def out():
    logger.warn('liba')
```

run python

```
$ python3 app.py 
liba
```

app.py output log to the logfile. liba.py does not output the log into the file. I want to save logs in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Do like so:

app.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.FileHandler('/tmp/app.log', 'a+')
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.warn('sample')

from lib import liba

liba.out()
```

lib/liba.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import logging    
def out():
    logging.warn('liba')
```

You don't need to instantiate the logging, unless you want to configure handlers, which you only do in your main script. Then all logging will go to the root logger which is what you get when instantiating with no specific name `logging.getLogger()`. I like to use it this way as you don't need to match names across all your modules for it to work. In your modules you just send log messages out by using `logging.warn('blabla')`. You further need to make sure you define all your handlers before any call to logging.warn is made, otherwise some default handler will take its place.